# How jsp maps to a portlet controller in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet, websphere-portal

I am using Spring Portlet MVC and Websphere Portal for my portlet application. In my jsp:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="saveFinishUrl">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="saveFinish" />
</portlet:actionURL>
```

Now, I have a controller class defined in my portlet.xml. In that class, I have a method called saveFinish annotated like this:

```
@ActionMapping(params = "action=saveFinish")
```

My question is that in the jsp there should be a mapping that maps the jsp to tejh controller class. Otherwise how does the portlet container know which controller class is supposed to handle the request?

I know that `<portlet:actionURL` will generate a url that will direct to the correct controller...but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsp in portlet environment is served by a particular portlet.

In case of spring  mvc the first jsp is decided by the controller that has a `@RenderMapping` for `view` mode.

Also you know that you can use the `action` attribute of `potlet:actionURL` tag to set the action, and then use it as a value of `@ActionMapping` annotation?

Comment: Thanks. But @ActionMapping is defined at a method level...not at the class level for the controller. My question is how the jsp knows to which controller class the request must go

Comment: @Kaushik it's portlet container's concern to send requests from actionURLs to the DispatcherPortlet that served the jsp.